# How can I improve the rails log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

At even moderate a request volume, the rails log in 3.2.x writes to the log blindly and ends up with multiple requests overlapping each other making it very difficult to parse and analyze.

What techniques exist for fixing this? My goal is to analyze for basic performance and exceptions and other debugging.

Thanks.

Comment: Make your question specific to the particular problem you are trying to solve, and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Do you run multiple rails server instances?

Comment: Yes. 4 instances and more at times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2

```
config.log_tags = [:uuid, :remote_ip]
```

will give each request a unique id that you can parse and group on

but really if you want performance and exception notification

- newrelic: http://newrelic.com/
- airbrake: https://airbrake.io/account/new?dev=true (NOTE: free dev 'sign up' link is good to get started with - find it at the bottom)